# Which is the best version of Ubuntu to use on a tablet device?

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, touchpad, touchscreen

can Ubuntu installed and use on xoom or ipad  ? ( or other touch screen monitor like kiosk ) . Is there a special build or package i need to install ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell: **No**.
My best advice is to buy yourself a decent tablet (so not an iPad).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like no news (thank god) about the (i-hate-it) iPad.

If you feel wild you can try on the xoom:

http://trsohmers.com/2011/03/06/how-to-run-ubuntu-on-the-motorola-xoom/

If you don't feel like fighting much I'd suggest a specific product:

http://www.alwaysinnovating.com/products/touchbook.htm